# Delete data from database in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I've been trying to delete data from a database in PHP but I am just getting errors. I've been getting the code from different tutorials and can't find the problem.
The error I'm getting: Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'u820209931'@'10.2.1.47' (using password: NO) in /home/u820209931/public_html/delete.php on line 12

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/u820209931/public_html/delete.php on line 12
Access denied for user 'u820209931'@'10.2.1.47' (using password: NO)

Index.php:`

```
<?
$servername = "Host";
$username = "User";
$password = "Pass";
$dbname = "DB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM People";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each rowDelite
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "ID: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"];
        echo "<a href=\"delete.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "\">Delete Name</a>";
        echo "</br>";
        echo "</br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);


?>`
```

Delete.php:

```
<?

    DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'User');
    DEFINE ('DB_PSWD', 'Pass');
    DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'Host');
    DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'DB');

    $dbcon = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD, DB_NAME);

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM people WHERE id = $_GET[id]") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Name has been deleted";
    header('Location: Index.php');

?>
```

Comment: use an ORM, cant believe in 2014 people still are using raw queries.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the link to the query, you should modify it like this:

```
mysqli_query($dbcon, "DELETE FROM people WHERE id = $_GET[id]")
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure the user **u820209931** on **10.2.1.47** host is exist and using the correct password.

Answer (score 0):

Use "mysqli_query" instead of  "mysql_query". Hope it will fix the error.

```
mysqli_query("DELETE FROM people WHERE id = $_GET[id]", $dbcon);
```